# Show HTML Slider variable derived through javascript on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, variables, canvas, slider

I have a slider that changes the width of circles on a bullseye on a canvas.  I want to display that bandwidth beneath the canvas. Like just a simple

Current bandwidth: x

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I've tried using span and documentwrite(), but part of the problem is I can't really figure out how to get the variable in the first place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="bullseye.js"></script>
  <title>Bull's Eye</title>            
</head>

<body> 
  <canvas id="testCanvas" style="border: 1px solid;" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>
  <p></p>   
  <div style="position:absolute; top:420px; left:10px">      
    <label for="radius">Bandwidth</label>
     <input type="range" id="width" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern()"></input>
     <p>Current Bandwidth: <span id="show"></span></p>    
   </div>    
 </body>

</html>
```

here is the javascript

```
var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

    win.onload = init;

    // canvas and context variables
    var canvas;
    var context;

    // center of the pattern
    var centerX, centerY;



    function init() {

            canvas = doc.getElementById("testCanvas");
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            centerX = canvas.width / 2;
            centerY = canvas.height / 2;

            drawPattern();
    }
    function drawPattern() {
        var width = doc.getElementById("width").value;
        var radius = 200;
        var colorTog = 1;

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


        while (radius > 0) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        if (colorTog == 1){
            context.fillStyle = 'red';
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        }
        context.fill();
        context.closePath();
        radius = radius - width;
        if (colorTog == 1){
            colorTog = 0;
        } else {
            colorTog = 1;
        }

        }
    }

    return {
        drawPattern: drawPattern

    };

})(window, document);
```

Comment: whats radius the value of range input?

Comment: The radius value is supposed set by the slider, correct? The code you've posted doesn't actually seem to do that (although we don't have the definition of `sliderModule`, so I don't know).

Comment: So basically I was trying to keep it simple and hoping you could just assume I have some variable from a slider that I want to print in html. but the slider determines width between circles, really. Doesn't matter; bottom line is I want that width variable to print in that "current bandwidth" sentence outside of the canvas.

Comment: `doc.getElementById("show").innerHTML= width;` Use this below your var width in the code

Comment: So simple and it worked immediately. Thanks a whole bunch, I knew I was missing something stupidly small.